# Spring Ajax List returned but objects empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, spring

I am building something like a locker management system and the lockers have an update history. I want use Ajax to return a list of of this history up to X entries in the list. Whenever I return `List<LockerHistoryEntity>` or `Iterable<LockerHistoryEntity>`, the amount of objects is returned, but all the objects are empty.

[Example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBo8o.png)

Ajax call (called upon with `getHistory(100)` in this case):

```
function getHistory(limit) {
    var data = {};
    data["limit"] = limit;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/gethistory",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 100000,
        success : function(data) {
            fillTable(data);
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.result);
        },
        error : function(e) {
            //error
        }
    });
}
```

@RestController

```
@JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/gethistory", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Iterable<LockerHistoryEntity> getHistory(@RequestBody HistoryLimit limit) {
        Iterable<LockerHistoryEntity> lockerHistory;

        if (limit.getLimit() >= 0) {
            lockerHistory = history.findAllLimit(limit.getLimit());
        } else {
            lockerHistory = history.findAll();
        }

        return lockerHistory;
    }
```

When using a for loop to print out `lockerHistory` the data is all displayed correctly.

Sadly, I couldn't find any topic about this exact problem, hence this post.

Comment: Have you tried to convert the object to JSON? I find some useful link here http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, solved it indeed. Forgot to parse to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the object into JSON form before sending the response to AJAX.
See this link: http://howtodoinjava.com/jackson/jackson-examples-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: Thanks, solved it using `ObjectMapper.mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(lockerHistory);` Returned the array of objects as String. For any future people, do not forget to use $.parseJSON() in the javascript on the string.